# Unable to use cell from XIB in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Here's my `DisruptionsViewController` which has the tableView. the function `setUp()` is used in another ViewController class to set up the `DisruptionsViewController`.

```
public class DisruptionsInfoViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setUp()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "DisruptionInfoTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "disruptionsInfoTableViewCell")
    }
    
    private func loadFromNib() -> UIView? {
        let nibName = String(describing: DisruptionsInfoViewController.self)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: Bundle(for: type(of: self)))
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
    }
    
    public func setUp() {
        guard let disruptionsInfoViewController = self.loadFromNib() else { return }
        disruptionsInfoViewController.frame = self.view.bounds
    }
    
}

extension DisruptionsInfoViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "disruptionsInfoTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? DisruptonInfoTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Here's the tableViewCell class.

```
import UIKit

class DisruptonInfoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!
}
```

I can see the tableView in the view debugger, but unable to see it in the view as the tableViewCell is not registered for some reason.

Here's how I am using it in another controller's delegate method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    guard let viewModel = presenter.headerViewModel(for: section) else { return nil }
    let dateSummaryView = DateSummaryView(frame: .zero)
    dateSummaryView.setup(with: viewModel)
    
    let disruptionsViewController = DisruptionsInfoViewController()
    
    return disruptionsViewController.view
}
```

Does anyone know where the problem could be?

I tried following tutorials from YouTube and other articles, they use the same approach but for some reason it doesn't work for me.

Comment: First, test this ***without*** the `setUp()` from another view controller. Second, in `cellForRowAt` do this: `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "disruptionsInfoTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DisruptonInfoTableViewCell` instead of the `guard`.

Comment: @DonMag, tried your recommendations but it's not working for me for some reason. I am trying to populate this View as a header for another tableView, But it's not allowing me to do it.

Comment: OK - then you need to show us what you're really trying to do. Tough to help when you post bits and pieces of information. Review [mre]

Comment: @DonMag, I have edited my question and shown how I use it another ViewController's delegate method.

Comment: Seeing only bits-and-pieces makes it very difficult to figure out what you're doing, and what might be wrong. However... in the `viewForHeaderInSection` code you added, as soon as you `return disruptionsViewController.view` that instance of `DisruptionsInfoViewController` no longer exists - all you've done is return its view. So none of its code can execute.

Comment: The function `setup` is pointless. It creates a local variable but does nothing with it, so it will be discarded as soon as the function returns.  And you don't seem to call it anyway. Similarly, your instantiation of `DisruptionsInfoViewController` in the table header method will result in an empty view for the table header since you don't instantiate the view controller  from a nib or with any other view content.

Comment: Hi @Paulw11, I am using the setUp() method in the viewDidLoad(). Just edited it. Also, the table view header nib is registered and displays all other elements except for the tableView. Do I need to do `tableView.datasource = self` in the viewController which has the header method?

Comment: `setup` still doesn't *do anything*. It gets a view from a nib, sets its frame and then throws that view away.

Comment: I'm 100% sure that you're not following any tutorial correctly, as your code is nonsense. You've really bolluxed yourself with the lying line `guard let disruptionsInfoViewController = self.loadFromNib()`. What you are loading is not a view controller, it's a view. And as you've been told, you then just throw that view away.

Comment: "setUp() is used in another ViewController class to set up the DisruptionsViewController". No. It doesn't set up anything.

Comment: "Does anyone know where the problem could be" Sure, it's that your code makes no sense.

Comment: @Paulw11, @matt, Thanks for your insight but, removing the `setUp()` results in the view not being rendered. As I said everything else in the view is displayed except for the tableView (which is shown in the debug view hierarchy but not displayed on screen). I have shared all the files/code relevant to this problem

Comment: @SJR5 - just a side note... check the reputation when someone comments on your question (hover over the name). It's generally not a good idea to argue with folks who have reps of `100,000+` as they probably know what they're talking about. ***None*** of your setUp() / loadFromNib() code is needed. The problem you are running into, as I mentioned in my previous comment, is that you are instantiating `DisruptionsInfoViewController` -- then grabbing its **view** -- then discarding the controller itself, so none of its table funcs can execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as mentioned in the comments, nothing in your `setUp()` is doing anything, so it can be removed.

The reason you are not seeing your table view rows in your other table's section header views is because here (I'll ignore the first three lines since they have nothing to do with this):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    //guard let viewModel = presenter.headerViewModel(for: section) else { return nil }
    //let dateSummaryView = DateSummaryView(frame: .zero)
    //dateSummaryView.setup(with: viewModel)
    
    let disruptionsViewController = DisruptionsInfoViewController()
    
    return disruptionsViewController.view

    // as soon as we return, disruptionsViewController is released
    //  and no code it contains will be executed
    
}
```

You created an instance of `DisruptionsInfoViewController`, pulled out its view, and then tossed away the controller code.

If you want to use this approach (rather odd, but we have to assume you have a logical reason to do this), you need to keep a reference to `DisruptionsInfoViewController` so its code can be used:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    
    let disruptionsViewController = DisruptionsInfoViewController()
    
    // add disruptionsViewController as a child view controller
    //  this will "hold on to it" so its code can execute
    addChild(disruptionsViewController)
    disruptionsViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
    
    return disruptionsViewController.view
    
}
```

Now, this is technically incorrect, as Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html) state:

> 1. Call the addChildViewController: method of your container view controller.
> 2. Add the child’s root view to your container’s view hierarchy.
> 3. Add any constraints for managing the size and position of the child’s root view.
> 4. Call the didMoveToParentViewController: method of the child view controller.

But, because we are returning the `view` for use as a section header view, we cannot perform `2.` before calling `didMove(toParent: self)`.

You didn't include in your post (or mention in your comments) how you're setting the **Height** of the section header, so, using:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 150.0
}
```

We get this with your original code - section header view background color is blue, the "table view in header view" background color is green:

[image]

and we get this when using `addChild()`:

[image]

Here is a complete example project: https://github.com/DonMag/Disrupt

While this *will* work, if you ***really*** want to embed a table view in another table view's section header(s), there are better ways to do it.

Comment: could you please also mention the other methods to achieve the same

Comment: @SJR5 - ideally, one would use a reusable `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` ... It is very difficult to try to give you any additional help, as you've continued to provide only minimal bits-and-pieces of code and information. Without additional details, the idea of using a *view containing a table view from a view controller xib* seems very odd. So, we have no idea what you are really trying to do, or what we could suggest as a better approach.